# Python Convert Excel tabs to CSV files

Tags: python, excel, csv, character-encoding, file-conversion

I've edited the post to reflect the changes recommended.

```
def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, Sheetname, CSVFile):
    import xlrd
    import csv

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Users\Programming\consolidateddataviewsyellowed.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name (ARC)
    csvfile = open (ARC.csv,'wb')
    wr = csv.writer (csvfile, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange (worksheet.nrows):
    wr.writerow(
        list(x.encode('utf-8') if type (x) == type (u'') else x
             for x in worksheet.row_values (rownum)))

    csvfile.close()


Excel2CSV("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Programming\consolidateddataviewsyellowed.xlsx","ARC","output.csv")
```

It displays the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Programming/ExceltoCSV.py", line 18, in <module>

  File "C:/Programming/ExceltoCSV.py", line 2, in Excel2CSV
import xlrd
ImportError: No module named xlrd
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are the spaces between your method names and arguments intentional? E.g. I would expect `.open_workbook(...)` not `.open_workbook (...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Response to edited code**

`No module named xlrd` indicates that you have not installed the `xlrd` library.  Bottom line, you need to install the xlrd module.  Installing a module is an important skill which beginner python users must learn and it can be a little hairy if you aren't tech savvy.  Here's where to get started.

First, check if you have pip (a module used to install other modules for python).  If you installed python recently and have up-to-date software, you almost certainly already have pip.  If not, see this detailed how-to answer elsewhere on stackoverflow:
[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Second, use pip to install the xlrd module.  The internet already has a trove of tutorials on this subject, so I will not outline this here.  Just Google: "how to pip install a module on *your OS here*"

Hope this helps!

**Old Answer**

your code looks good..  Here's the test case I ran using mostly what your wrote.  Note that I changed your function so that it uses the arguments rather than hardcoded values.  that may be where your trouble is?

```
def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, Sheetname, CSVFile):
    import xlrd
    import csv

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook (ExcelFile)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name (Sheetname)
    csvfile = open (CSVFile,'wb')
    wr = csv.writer (csvfile, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
        wr.writerow(
            list(x.encode('utf-8') if type (x) == type (u'') else x
                 for x in worksheet.row_values (rownum)))

    csvfile.close()

Excel2CSV("C:\path\to\XLSXfile.xlsx","Sheet_Name","C:\path\to\CSVfile.csv")
```

Double check that the arguments you are passing are all correct.

Comment: Excel2CSV("C:\Users\R\Desktop\pythontestfile.xlsx","Sheet1","output.csv")Should I replace the extension with my Excel sheet location. I removed the from os import sys from my script and it still runs blank no error.

Comment: Right, replace those inputs with your filelocation, the sheet name and the name of the output csv file.  Note that they are strings and should be in quotes.